# No coverage report in gitlab despite valid regex and activated parsing

Tags: c#, .net-core, gitlab, code-coverage

So I have a netstandard library with a test project, nothing too large. This gets built and tested by Gitlab CI via dotnet test and coverlet. Part of the test's output will be this coverage report:

```
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
|         | Line   | Branch | Method |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
| Total   | 90.87% | 67.66% | 94.32% |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
| Average | 90.87% | 67.66% | 94.32% |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Now Gitlab uses regex to parse that, so naturally I have this regex parsing the first value:

```
Total\s*\|\s*(\d+\.\d+)%
```

I put it in in the coverage parsing setting under settings > general pipelines, and also added `coverage: /Total\s*\|\s*(\d+\.\d+)%/` to the job in the .gitlab-ci.yml. I validated the regex using rubular, as Gitlab suggested: https://rubular.com/r/LOazRNRFmChzIr and it confirms my regex will find that coverage amount.

And yet, there is no coverage to be seen anywhere. The badge I added to the project also shows "coverage: unknown".

Is something still missing?

Comment: Copied your RegEx and it worked for me. Did you verify this output is successfully created when you view the logs from the test runner in gitlab, and that it is blank on the pipeline jobs page?

Comment: Yes, the pipeline output shows all coverage output (more than this table, but this is the one I want to match), and there is no coverage indicator on the job's page or the merge request page. I have pipelines for feature/develop/master now and neither show coverage.

Comment: @James turns out I lied: I did not correctly verify the output. I looked at it and it looked right, but I didn't realize the decimal separators were different.

Answer (score 1):

Alright time to make myself look stupid.

I copypasted the table from my local machine's output into rubular.

Turns out the test runner uses commas a decimal separators, while my local machine uses periods. That is all.

Answer (score 1):

Warning, as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72735773/6309) by [Drikus Roor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4496102/drikus-roor), since GitLab 14.8, the test coverage parsing setting has been [deprecated](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#add-test-coverage-results-using-project-settings-removed) and has been removed since GitLab 15.0.

You would therefore **no longer** be able to set your (with commas) regex through `Settings > CI/CD > General pipelines`. But you would have to use the `coverage` setting in your GitLab CI/CD configuration file and use your regular expression in the setting value:

```yaml
unit-test:
  stage: test
  coverage: 'Total\s*\|\s*(\d+\,\d+)%'
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow for 100% coverage, you can use:

```
test:
  ...
  coverage: /Total\s*\|\s*(\d+\.?\d+)%/
```