# I cannot find Gitlab's test coverage parsing setting in my CI/CD settings

Tags: regex, gitlab, gitlab-ci, code-coverage

I would like to set the regular expression for my test coverage results.

According to [Gitlab's documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/14.10/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#add-test-coverage-results-using-project-settings-deprecated), I should be able to do that in the test coverage parsing setting in my project settings, by navigating to `Settings > CI/CD > General pipelines`.

However, I cannot find the setting there. Where can I set the regular expression for the test coverage parsing setting in Gitlab?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since Gitlab 14.8, the test coverage parsing setting has been [deprecated](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#add-test-coverage-results-using-project-settings-removed) and has been removed since Gitlab 15.0. The setting can therefore **no longer** be found in `Settings > CI/CD > General pipelines`.

You should now use the `coverage` setting in your Gitlab CI/CD configuration file and use your regular expression in the setting value:

**Example:**

```yaml
unit-test:
  stage: test
  coverage: '/coverage: \d+.\d+% of statements/'
  script:
    - go test -cover
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that this style of coverage reporting is not accurate if your application has several packages.